# Java - OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an string arraylist with a size 100,000, wherein every element after the first two is the previous two strings concatenated. The problem is, I run out of memory before I even reach 100 strings. I plan to use this arraylist to do a binary search and output a letter in the string based on the input given, which is the index of the string, and the index of the letter within the string.

Here's the code

```
    public static void generateSequence(int numStrings, ArrayList<String> input){
        String temp = "", S1, S2;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                input.add("H");
            }
            else if(i == 1) {
                input.add("A");
            }
            else {
                S1 = input.get(input.size() - 2);
                S2 = input.get(input.size() - 1);
                temp = S1.concat(S2);
                input.add(temp);
                temp = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to be more efficient with the memory usage to get the arraylist I need for this, so any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Could you increase the heap size? That might work for you. In theory, you could only store the addition, and have it dynamically generate each string on the fly. But then you're trading less memory usage for for CPU. Also, if you know the total size (which you do, and for the Strings, you can calculate), then why not use a normal array? They will be far more efficient than an ArrayList. You could generate that array in your method and then return it maybe

Comment: The length of your elements will be part of a Fibonacci series. If the length of the first two elements are zero and one, then [the length of element 100 will be 354,224,848,179,261,915,075](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/fibtable.html). Good luck getting to 100,00 elements!

Comment: You're out of memory because you're using all the memory. You're attempting to produce strings that are exabytes in size. There is no way to be "more efficient" and still produce these strings, instead you need to describe the actual problem you're solving. If this is for some programming contest, then the lesson you're certainly mean to learn is that you can't always instantiate an entire sequence to solve a problem.

Comment: @user229044 While it might be argued that this question could/should be closed for some custom reason, a close reason of _"caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced"_ is completely inappropriate. The issue is certainly not due to _"a typo"_, and it can easily be reproduced. And I don't see how the OP could express the problem much more clearly.

Comment: What kind of nonsense is closed "not reproducible or caused by typos"?  It's eminently reproducible. There is a minor typo ('n' should be 'numStrings') but that is a transcription error.  The question is a good one, and the answer is a good lesson to the naive programmer.

Comment: @skomisa *"While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*. There is nothing useful for future readers here, the problem is simple memory exhaustion. The problem, as stated, is not solvable because there is not enough memory in existence to run this program.

Comment: @user229044 - "what not to do" is surely useful for future readers.

Comment: @danglingelse How is this extremely specific bit of code  useful to anybody? The entire question is, when reduced to its simplest form, "why do I get an out-of-memory error when I try to allocate more memory than there are elementary particles in the universe?"  Allocating more memory than there can ever be is not a useful problem, and it's not a problem that people *have*, so it is fundamentally not reproducible. Nobody actually has that problem.

Comment: @user229044 Well I certainly disagree that _"There is nothing useful for future readers here"_; what is obvious to some is not certainly not automatically obvious to others. But my larger concern is that you are using a bogus close reason to force close the question. That's indefensible.

Comment: The lesson is rather: estimate the memory requirements of your algorithm.

Comment: Again, if the question were worded "Why can't I allocate more bytes of ram than there are elementary particles in the universe?", would you consider that a real, reproducible problem? I'm not talking about a *runnable piece of code*, I'm stating that the problem OP claims to have is not the problem they actually have, or a problem anybody has or can have.

Comment: @skomisa - I agree: the lack of the slightest effort to provide a valid close reason shows lack of concern for the OP.

Comment: *"Why can't I allocate more bytes of ram than there are elementary particles in the universe?"* - I think you're missing the point of the lesson, which is to estimate your memory requirements.  Only after you've done that can you realize the universe is too small.

Comment: @user229044 Re _"Nobody actually has that problem"_, oh for goodness sake. It may be a homework assignment! And since when has that ever been a justification to automatically close a question? No wonder new OPs are completely turned off by Stack Overflow when their question is closed in this manner.

Comment: @user229044 And why are you using the wording _"why do I get an out-of-memory error when I try to allocate more memory than there are elementary particles in the universe?"_. Your comment is rude and condescending, and a complete complete distortion of the question that was asked.

Answer (score 7):

So the N<sup>th</sup> element is the concatenation of the N-1<sup>th</sup> and N-2<sup>th</sup> elements?

Thus the length of the N<sup>th</sup> element is the sum of the lengths of the two previous elements.

You're talking about a huge amount of storage. This code shows you how much storage the N<sup>th</sup> entry needs.

```
    double n0 = 1, n1 = 1;
    for (int i=2; i<=100; i++) {
        double n2 = n1 + n0;
        System.out.printf("%4d : %e\n", i, n2);
        n0 = n1;
        n1 = n2;
    }
```

The 49th entry has 12 billion characters (so that's about 24 billion characters overall; or about 48 GB).

The 100th entry (counting from 1) has over 5 x 10<sup>20</sup> characters.

You need to rethink your data structure.